# geting ams an xml bind exception while using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have created the below swing form which will take some parameters
from user in the form and when user hit the button generatenetworkmodel an xml should be generated and in those xml the input value would be the same which user had eneterd in the text box as shown

The xml that i want to be generated and written in JTextPane within the form is is ..

Now I have chosen the approach of jaxb and have developed the below pojo..

```
package abcd;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement(name = "route")
public class Route {



    @XmlAttribute(name = "cna")
    protected String cna;
    public String getCna(){ return cna; }
    public void setCna( String value ){ cna = value; }



    @XmlAttribute(name = "typ")
    protected String typ;
    public String getTyp() {
        return typ;
    }
    public void setTyp(String typ) {
        this.typ = typ;
    }



    @XmlAttribute(name = "gelcatnumbersink")
    protected String gelcatnumbersink;
    public String getGelcatnumbersink() {
        return gelcatnumbersink;
    }
    public void setGelcatnumbersink(String gelcatnumbersink) {
        this.gelcatnumbersink = gelcatnumbersink;
    }



    @XmlAttribute(name = "gelcatnumbersource")
    protected String gelcatnumbersource;
    public String getGelcatnumbersource() {
        return gelcatnumbersource;
    }
    public void setGelcatnumbersource(String gelcatnumbersource) {
        this.gelcatnumbersource = gelcatnumbersource;
    }



    @XmlAttribute(name = "postfiltertype")
    protected String postfiltertype;
    public String getPostfiltertype() {
        return postfiltertype;
    }
    public void setPostfiltertype(String postfiltertype) {
        this.postfiltertype = postfiltertype;
    }



    @XmlAttribute(name = "postfilterfilename")
    protected String postfilterfilename;
    public String getPostfilterfilename() {
        return postfilterfilename;
    }
    public void setPostfilterfilename(String postfilterfilename) {
        this.postfilterfilename = postfilterfilename;
    }



    @XmlAttribute(name = "prefiltertype")
    protected String prefiltertype;
    public String getPrefiltertype() {
        return prefiltertype;
    }
    public void setPrefiltertype(String prefiltertype) {
        this.prefiltertype = prefiltertype;
    }



    @XmlAttribute(name = "prefilterfilename")
    protected String prefilterfilename;
public String getPrefilterfilename() {
        return prefilterfilename;
    }
    public void setPrefilterfilename(String prefilterfilename) {
        this.prefilterfilename = prefilterfilename;
    }



    @XmlAttribute(name = "sk_ver")
    protected String sk_ver;
     public String getSk_ver() {
        return sk_ver;
    }
    public void setSk_ver(String sk_ver) {
        this.sk_ver = sk_ver;
    }



    @XmlAttribute(name = "sk_typ")
        protected String sk_typ;
     public String getSk_typ() {
        return sk_typ;
    }
    public void setSk_typ(String sk_typ) {
        this.sk_typ = sk_typ;
    }



    @XmlAttribute(name = "sk_cna")
    protected String sk_cna;
      public String getSk_cna() {
        return sk_cna;
    }
    public void setSk_cna(String sk_cna) {
        this.sk_cna = sk_cna;
    }



    @XmlAttribute(name = "ver")
    protected String ver;
    public String getVer() {
        return ver;
    }
    public void setVer(String ver) {
        this.ver = ver;
    }



}
```

and below is my swing form upon which hit button I have to generate the xml..

```
public class sdr {

    private JFrame frmArgonNetworkModel;
    private final JButton btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel = new JButton("GenerateAgonNetworkModel");
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;
    private JTextField textField_4;
    private JTextField textField_5;
    private JTextField textField_6;
    private JTextField textField_7;
    private JTextField textField_8;
    private JTextField textField_9;
    private JTextField textField_10;
    private JTextField textField_11;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sdr window = new sdr();
                    window.frmArgonNetworkModel.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public sdr() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmArgonNetworkModel = new JFrame();
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().setForeground(new Color(188, 143, 143));
        frmArgonNetworkModel.setForeground(new Color(245, 222, 179));
        frmArgonNetworkModel.setTitle("Argon Network Model");
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().setBackground(UIManager.getColor("ToolBar.light"));
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel.setBackground(new Color(224, 255, 255));
        btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel.setBounds(223, 329, 196, 29);

        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Route CNA");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(22, 11, 71, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblTyp = new JLabel("typ");
        lblTyp.setBounds(22, 36, 71, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblTyp);

        JLabel lblSkcna = new JLabel("sk_cna");
        lblSkcna.setBounds(22, 67, 71, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblSkcna);

        JLabel lblSktyp = new JLabel("sk_typ");
        lblSktyp.setBounds(22, 92, 71, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblSktyp);

        JLabel lblSkver = new JLabel("sk_ver");
        lblSkver.setBounds(22, 117, 71, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblSkver);

        JLabel lblPrefilterfilename = new JLabel("prefilterfilename");
        lblPrefilterfilename.setBounds(22, 142, 105, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblPrefilterfilename);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(122, 8, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(122, 33, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setBounds(122, 64, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_2);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);

        textField_3 = new JTextField();
        textField_3.setBounds(122, 89, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_3);
        textField_3.setColumns(10);

        textField_4 = new JTextField();
        textField_4.setBounds(122, 114, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_4);
        textField_4.setColumns(10);

        textField_5 = new JTextField();
        textField_5.setBounds(122, 139, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_5);
        textField_5.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("prefiltertype");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(22, 167, 88, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

        textField_6 = new JTextField();
        textField_6.setBounds(122, 164, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_6);
        textField_6.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("postfilterfilename");
        lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(22, 192, 88, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_2);

        textField_7 = new JTextField();
        textField_7.setBounds(122, 189, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_7);
        textField_7.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("postfiltertype");
        lblNewLabel_3.setBounds(22, 217, 86, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_3);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_4 = new JLabel("xfm");
        lblNewLabel_4.setBounds(22, 240, 46, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_4);

        textField_8 = new JTextField();
        textField_8.setBounds(122, 214, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_8);
        textField_8.setColumns(10);

        textField_9 = new JTextField();
        textField_9.setBounds(122, 237, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_9);
        textField_9.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_5 = new JLabel("gelcatnumbersource");
        lblNewLabel_5.setBounds(22, 265, 116, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_5);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_6 = new JLabel("gelcatnumbersink");
        lblNewLabel_6.setBounds(22, 290, 88, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_6);

        textField_10 = new JTextField();
        textField_10.setBounds(122, 262, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_10);
        textField_10.setColumns(10);

        textField_11 = new JTextField();
        textField_11.setBounds(120, 290, 379, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_11);
        textField_11.setColumns(10);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setBounds(22, 369, 652, 186);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textPane);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.setBounds(100, 100, 711, 613);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel.setActionCommand("generate");
        btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel.addActionListener(new ButtonClickListener());
    }

    public class ButtonClickListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if ("generate".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                // create the Route object
                // marshal to string
                // ...

                Route route = new Route();
                route.setCna( "cnavalue" );
                try 
                {
                JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( Route.class );
                Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
                m.setProperty( "jaxb.fragment", true );
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                m.marshal( route, sw );
                System.out.println( sw.toString() );
                }catch(Exception ee)
                {ee.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }




}
}
```

now rite now i am getting following exception...

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 12 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "cna"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String abcd.Route.getCna()
        at abcd.Route
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.lang.String abcd.Route.cna
        at abcd.Route
Class has two properties of the same name "gelcatnumbersink"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String abcd.Route.getGelcatnumbersink()
        at abcd.Route
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.lang.String abcd.Route.gelcatnumbersink
        at abcd.Route
Class has two properties of the same name "gelcatnumbersource"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String abcd.Route.getGelcatnumbersource()
        at abcd.Route
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.lang.String abcd.Route.gelcatnumbersource
        at abcd.Route
Class has two properties of the same name "postfilterfilename"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String abcd.Route.getPostfilterfilename()
        at abcd.Route
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.lang.String abcd.Route.postfilterfilename
        at abcd.Route
Class has two properties of the same name "postfiltertype"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String abcd.Route.getPostfiltertype()
        at abcd.Route
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.lang.String abcd.Route.postfiltertype
        at abcd.Route
Class has two properties of the same name "prefilterfilename"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String abcd.Route.getPrefilterfilename()
        at abcd.Route
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.lang.String abcd.Route.prefilterfilename
        at abcd.Route
Class has two properties of the same name "prefiltertype"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String abcd.Route.getPrefiltertype()
        at abcd.Route
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.lang.String abcd.Route.prefiltertype
        at abcd.Route
Class has two properties of the same name "sk_cna"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String abcd.Route.getSk_cna()
        at abcd.Route
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.lang.String abcd.Route.sk_cna
        at abcd.Route
Class has two properties of the same name "sk_typ"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String abcd.Route.getSk_typ()
        at abcd.Route
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.lang.String abcd.Route.sk_typ
        at abcd.Route
Class has two properties of the same name "sk_ver"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String abcd.Route.getSk_ver()
        at abcd.Route
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.lang.String abcd.Route.sk_ver
        at abcd.Route
Class has two properties of the same name "typ"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String abcd.Route.getTyp()
        at abcd.Route
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.lang.String abcd.Route.typ
        at abcd.Route
Class has two properties of the same name "ver"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String abcd.Route.getVer()
        at abcd.Route
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.lang.String abcd.Route.ver
        at abcd.Route

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at abcd.sdr$ButtonClickListener.actionPerformed(sdr.java:209)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default JAXB treats properties as mapped.  Since you have annotated the fields JAXB now thinks you have a field an property with the same name mapped.  To solve this problem you can do one of the following:

- Annotate the properties (get or set methods) instead of the fields.
- Keep the annotations on the fields and annotate the class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.

Comment: i have added the following property @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD). in fromt of claass qas shown @XmlRootElement(name = "route")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Route {

Comment: but it is showing complation error could ypu please advise

Comment: @user3787668 - What compilation error are you getting?